# How can I evenly space buttons on the top navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I am working on an application with a top navigation bar.  I need eight buttons in that bar. The bottom tool bar is not used. My problem is evenly spacing the buttons.

Five buttons auto-position on the left. Three go right, with a big gap in the middle. Inserting a `Flexible` or `Fixed` space bar item does not work. Inserting one of these spacers on the top bar makes the `Flexible` or `Fixed` space item appear on the bottom tool bar, where I don't want it.

Is there a center function? I tried using constraints, but then when the phone is rotated things get pushed around all wrong again.

Comment: What do you mean flexible space did not work? what did you try exactly?

Comment: On a view controller i added a Navigation bar at the top. I then dragged in 8 Bar Button item.   Doing this 5 get forced to the left side of the Navigation bar and three get forced to the right of the Navigation bar. This now leaves a strange gap between button 5 and 6 that is off balance.  The buttons will not evenly space across the bar.   Swift has a component called "Flexible Space Bar Button Item" and also a "Fixed Space Bar Button Item"   these are used to add spaces between buttons.   These two components works perfectly when added to the tool bar that is at the bottom of the IOS screen